# Ansible 'Failed to connect to the host via ssh'

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, connection, ansible

I know this has been asked a lot, but I've tried every solution I've seen over like 20 threads on the web and nothing has worked for me yet.

I'm on an Ubuntu 16.10 Linux local machine using ansible 2.1.1.0 trying to ping (`ansible all -m ping`) my Ansible child node that's on an Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance.

My /etc/ansible/hosts has the EC2's public IP:

```
web1 ansible_host=52.91.x.y
```

I can SSH into the EC2 instance with:

```
ssh -i "mypemfile.pem" ubuntu@52.91.x.y
```

so I know the security group/networking/etc. is fine on the instance.

But when I try to ping the child nodes:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

I get:

```
Failed to connect to the host via ssh
```

When I show the full command by -vvvv:

```
ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/myuser/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 52.91.x.y
```

and then run that command that Ansible is running, at the end of the detailed output, it shows:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: Downloads/nginx-code-challenge-2017-03-16.pem
...skip some stuff
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

It tries a bunch of different keys from my local (Ansible master node) system without success.

I made sure the public key of my master node is in `.ssh/authorized_keys` of the child node. When I do ssh-copy-id it confirms this, saying the key has already been added.

I've tried specifying the path to my private key in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg, but this does nothing, and I can already see in the debug output that it is trying several keys.

I've tried adding the `-c paramiko` command:

```
ansible all -m ping -vvvv -c paramiko
```

But all I get is a new error, `Authentication failed`

I even tried crazy stuff like `host_key_checking = False` in ansible.cfg

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Your manual SSH login is using your correct identity file (the *.pem one)

```
ssh -i "mypemfile.pem" ubuntu@52.91.x.y
```

However Ansible is reaching out to your public key file and using that as the private identity file:

```
 'IdentityFile="/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"'
```

The **IdentityFile** argument expects a private key file. You'll want it to point to "mypemfile.pem" too.

#### Suggestion

Add the remote virtual machine to your SSH config file at ~/.ssh/config

```
  Host ec2
       HostName  something.compute.amazonaws.com 
       User ec2-user
       IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/mypemfile.pem
```

Then your hosts file for Ansible becomes much simpler:

```
 [EC2]
 dev ansible_ssh_host=ec2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however, it is trying that key too. :-( In the output it has "debug1: Offering RSA public key: Downloads/nginx-code-challenge-2017-03-16.pem", which is my private key for the AWS instance

Comment: I even tried --private-key="path_to_aws_key" with no luck

Comment: I'll try your config file option.. hang on

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference having that .ssh/config file

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being stupidly simple. I was missing the user in the /etc/ansible/hosts (the **ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu** portion):

```
[nginx]
web1 ansible_ssh_host=52.91.x.y ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```